# Can you checkin/checkout Visual Studio 2008 BIDS SSIS packages to TFS 2013 source control?

Tags: tfs, bids

Does Visual Studio 2008 BID's allow you to checkin and checkout SSIS packages in TFS 2013?  What do I need to add or configure in VS 2008 BID's to interact with TFS 2013?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Nick, the edition of Team Explorer that comes with Visual Studio 2008 is no longer supported. You need to download the [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 MSSCCI Provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/06c8e056-7f77-4a5c-9b8b-49318c143df8). Once installed if you go to Tools | Settings | Source Control you will be able to select it and connect to TFS 2013. This will however only give you Source Control access and no integration with Work Item tracking.

I would recommend upgrading you SQL Server at the earliest opportunity as I do believe that you will loose mainstream support in January 2015...